# windows azure code reference

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone

I'm working with windows phone apps that using windows azure service to insert,update,read and delete and from [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-data/) I only find several code reference for basic use, where can i get a much advance code for example,

I want to read data from table address where the table id is "01231" and username is "user1" 
and here is what my database look like:

table: address
id:string
name:string
userid:string

table: user
userid:string
username:string

how get documentation about all these operation? what i only get is

```
addressItem = await addressTable
                  .Where(table => table.placeId == hereRestDetail.placeId)
                  .ToCollectionAsync();
```

that use for getting data from addresstable where placeid = my own placeid that come from rest service

Answer (score 0):

As long as table.placeId and hereRestDetail.placeId are the same type the above is a valid way to match entries.  Take a look here for more examples: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-add-paging-data/